# How can I reset tmux's automatic session name numbering?

Tags: tmux

After accidentally holding down ctrl+alt+t, my tmux sessions are now automatically named with annoyingly high numbers:

```
llama@llama:~$ tmux ls
124: 1 windows (created Mon Jan  5 16:45:55 2015) [80x24] (attached)
```

How can I reset this number to `1`? I've tried `tmux rename-session`'ing my session to a lower number, but after closing it and opening a new session, the numbering resumes from the original number.

Is there any way to fix this without restarting tmux?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible.

The only thing you can do about this without restarting the server is to override the name manually when creating a new session by issuing `tmux new -s 5`, for example:

```sh
$ tmux new -d -P
10:
$ tmux ls
10: 1 windows (created Wed Jan  7 15:50:29 2015) [107x89]
$ tmux new -s 5 -d -P
5:
$ tmux ls
10: 1 windows (created Wed Jan  7 15:50:29 2015) [107x89]
5: 1 windows (created Wed Jan  7 15:50:40 2015) [107x89]
$ tmux new -s 5 -d -P
duplicate session: 5
```

---

The automatic session number is governed by the global variable `u_int next_session_id` in [`session.c`](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/tmux/session.c?annotate=1.46) which cannot be accessed from the command line, as grepping the source code reveals.

`tmux new-session` calls `session_create()` in [`session.c`](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/tmux/session.c?annotate=1.46) (line 88) and `next_session_id` is incremented whenever you create a new session.  The argument of `-s` flag to `new-session` (short `new`) sets `name`, otherwise `next_session_id` is used.

```c
     if (name != NULL) {
              s->name = xstrdup(name);
              s->id = next_session_id++;
     } else {
             s->name = NULL;
             do {
                     s->id = next_session_id++;
                     free(s->name);
                     xasprintf(&s->name, "%u", s->id);
             } while (RB_FIND(sessions, &sessions, s) != NULL);
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
tmux kill-server && tmux
```